# Best practice to return Type id descriptions for api consumers

Tags: rest, api

I am developing an api for clients to consume.

Some of the objects e.g. telephone, where a person could have more than one telephone will have multiple type id's. I have a list of telephone types server side and the consumer will be required to either pass no value and it will default this or pass an id to represent the correct value. Now this in itself is not my issue however when you expand the type id's across many, many objects you arrive at my question.

If as a developer you're consuming the API data, would you prefer a single URI end point to retrieve all the type id's and descriptions, or multiple end points to call for each type id list (which would and has driven me nuts previously with other API's) or just document all the Id's (although this is a moving target always)

Basically clients will push their data into the system via the API, we will then process the data in some way and they will build reports from the data processed.

So what's preferred?

Single end point
GET: domain/root/allTypes

```
{
"TelephoneTypes":[
  {"id": 123, "description":"Home"},
  ...
  {"id": 789, "description":"Mobile"}
]
},
"EmailTypes":[
  {"id": 234, "description":"personal"},
  ...
  {"id": 567, "description":"work"}
]
}
```

Or

Multiple end points
GET: domain/root/telephone/types

```
{
"TelephoneTypes":[
  {"id": 123, "description":"Home"},
  ...
  {"id": 789, "description":"Mobile"}
]
}
```

GET: domain/root/email/types

```
{
"EmailTypes":[
  {"id": 234, "description":"personal"},
  ...
  {"id": 567, "description":"work"}
]
}
```

I'm sure context will effect the outcome and I've tried to give as simple a scope to the question. I'm really interested in the general preferred consumption approach as I've used several API's and added to many more but this is a greenfield project so I want to try and find the overall preferred method to passify the end users/developers and keep my sanity :)